# Clang Tooling Preprocess Source Files

Tags: c++, parsing, clang, libclang

I am using the Clang::Tooling library to parse some header files.  I can't seem to parse properly due to clang not pre-processing header files and other pre-processor stuff.  How can I tell Clang::Tooling to pre-process files before parsing. Cheers.  This is my current code for invoking my tool.

```
/*static*/ SAST SAST::Parse( CFile& HeaderFile, const TArray<CString>& CommandLineArgs )
{
    //Our Custom Formated Ast Data Struct
    SAST AST;

    //Parse Command-Line Args.
    clang::tooling::CommandLineArguments CommandArgs;
    for (auto& Item : CommandLineArgs)
        CommandArgs.push_back(Item.GetRaw());

    //Traverse And Collect AST
    auto SourceText = HeaderFile.GetText();
    auto SourceFileName = HeaderFile.GetFullName();
    clang::tooling::runToolOnCodeWithArgs(new CollectASTAction(&AST), SourceText.GetRawConst(), CommandArgs);

    return AST;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it actually is trying to pre-process the file.  I couldn't see any errors reported due to no console window open.  However, when I inspected the **llvm::raw_fd_ostream** class's **write()** method with a break-point, I could see that errors were being written such as **"FileXXX.h could not be found"**.  So it simply couldn't find the **#include** files.  That's why pre-processing wasn't performed/completed.  Thanks everyone.  This solves my day long journey.

Comment: How did you specify include files to a clang tool? -I didnt work for me